# Iterate within View in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for creating a SQL view where I have data as per the below screenshot

[image]

I want to convert rows into columns but based on # of Months. For Example, if # Month is 3 then add value to Jan, Feb, and Mar, and so on.

[image]

Comment: This requires dynamic SQL . . . and I would suggest avoiding that if possible.  On the other hand, you could put the data in separate rows.

Comment: Considering that the months of the year are known, you don't specifically need dynamic SQL if you set the view up to always display January to December.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select ID
       ,case when Months >= 1 then Salary else null end Jan
       ,case when Months >= 2 then Salary else null end Feb
       ,case when Months >= 3 then Salary else null end Mar
       ,case when Months >= 4 then Salary else null end Apr
       ,case when Months >= 5 then Salary else null end May
from some_table
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution should look like this:

1. First create a table or function to return your cross reference of Months to their abbreviations. Going simple, it looks like:

```
Create Table MonthDef (
  MonthID int,
  MonthAbbr varchar(3)
);
```

2. Join the table above with your salary to convert your salary data to have month detail granularity

```
with SalaryMonthDetail as
(
 select SalaryID, Salary, MonthAbbr from Salaries s inner join MonthDef m on s.months>=m.MonthID
)
```

3. Pivot the result and convert those rows to columns

```
select *
from SalaryMonthDetail
PIVOT(
    Min(Salary) 
    FOR MonthAbbr IN (
        [Jan], 
        [Feb], 
        [Mar], 
        [Apr], 
        [May], 
        [Jun], 
        [Jul],
        [Aug],
        [Sep],
        [Oct],
        [Nov],
        [Dec]
    )
) AS pivot_sal;
```

4. Put 2 to 3 in a view and select like seen [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2bf374/1)

Comment: This was working but another solution was easy to understand and implement.

Comment: Yeah I saw that too and it looked elegant. For better or worse, I tend to provide answers that can be derived from data i.e. let the sql do the work from the data. I saw that you had column summary output which doesn’t usually occur unless aggregated from row data or accommodating inherited bad modeling. So I felt the need to present the actual row data that gets summarized to columns. Both options are good to have depending on actual scenario - say you need to add a year and summarize row data, you would use sums and group bys on row data instead of additions of columns in the query.