# Iterate within View in SQL Server - Dynamic positioning

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for creating a SQL view where I have data as per the below screenshot

[image]

I want to convert rows into columns but based on # of Months. For Example, if # Month is 3 then add value to Jan, Feb, and Mar, and so on BUT the additional condition is to start iteration based on starting of DOJ Month.

So in this scenario, the desired output will be [image]

Note: I have asked for something similar previously but it does not cover the additional scenario. Refer: [Iterate within View in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66249244/iterate-within-view-in-sql-server)

Comment: Will you have cases that span across Dec ? like `Months = 2` and `DJOMonth = December`

Comment: How is this different from your previous question? If the number of columns or their names / datatypes changes based on some other attribute, then you can't do this in a view.

Comment: Focus on the positioning. Besides the reason I have asked this separately is to avoid confusion with the past scenario. Happy to explain this further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `DOJMonth` is a string, you need to convert to integer month no to make thing easier.

Once that is settled, you can use `CROSS APPLY` to work out the individual month salary

```
with mthref as
(
    select *
    from   (
               values
               ('Jan', 1), ('Feb', 2), ('Mar', 3), ('Apr', 4), ('May', 5), ('Jun', 6),
               ('Jul', 7), ('Aug', 8), ('Sep', 9), ('Oct',10), ('Nov',11), ('Dec',12)
           ) M (DOJMonth, MthNo)
)
select s.ID, m.*
from  sample s
      inner join mthref r on s.DOJMonth = r.DOJMonth
      cross apply
      (
          select [Jan] = case when r.MthNo <= 1 and r.MthNo + Months > 1 then Salary end,
                 [Feb] = case when r.MthNo <= 2 and r.MthNo + Months > 2 then Salary end,          
                 [Mar] = case when r.MthNo <= 3 and r.MthNo + Months > 3 then Salary end,          
                 [Apr] = case when r.MthNo <= 4 and r.MthNo + Months > 4 then Salary end,          
                 [May] = case when r.MthNo <= 5 and r.MthNo + Months > 5 then Salary end,          
                 [Jun] = case when r.MthNo <= 6 and r.MthNo + Months > 6 then Salary end,          
                 [Jul] = case when r.MthNo <= 7 and r.MthNo + Months > 7 then Salary end,          
                 [Aug] = case when r.MthNo <= 8 and r.MthNo + Months > 8 then Salary end,          
                 [Sep] = case when r.MthNo <= 9 and r.MthNo + Months > 9 then Salary end,          
                 [Oct] = case when r.MthNo <= 10 and r.MthNo + Months > 10 then Salary end,          
                 [Nov] = case when r.MthNo <= 11 and r.MthNo + Months > 11 then Salary end,          
                 [Dec] = case when r.MthNo <= 12 and r.MthNo + Months > 12 then Salary end
      ) m;
```

In the following fiddle demo, there is also another solution using `pivot`. Both solution needs to translate the month string (eg. `Mar`) to integer (`3`)

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a9c7517af8904a9fca1eaf9210855ed1)

Comment: Simple yet powerful Query. I was able to solve the puzzle that was missing. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Though the code looks little large and bit naive but I have done this with one `CTE` and `CASE` . Here is my code given below=> CHECK LINK [DB-FIDDLE DEMO LINK](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=979b7de7c794006a8f397134f3883e1d)

```
DECLARE @MYTable Table(ID int,SALARY DECIMAL(18,2),Months INT,DOJMONTH VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @MYTable VALUES(1,6000,3,'MARCH');
INSERT INTO @MYTable VALUES(2,4000,5,'JUNE');
INSERT INTO @MYTable VALUES(3,7000,4,'MARCH');

WITH CTE AS
(SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN DOJMONTH='January' THEN 1 
         WHEN DOJMONTH='February' THEN 2
         WHEN DOJMONTH='March' THEN 3
         WHEN DOJMONTH='April' THEN 4  
         WHEN DOJMONTH='May' THEN 5
         WHEN DOJMONTH='June' THEN 6
         WHEN DOJMONTH='July' THEN 7
         WHEN DOJMONTH='August' THEN 8
         WHEN DOJMONTH='September' THEN 9
         WHEN DOJMONTH='October' THEN 10
         WHEN DOJMONTH='November' THEN 11
         WHEN DOJMONTH='December' THEN 12 ELSE NULL END MonthNum
FROM @MYTable
)
SELECT ID,
 CASE WHEN DOJMONTH='January' OR
            (MonthNum=1 AND ((MonthNum+Months)-1)>=1)
            THEN SALARY
          ELSE NULL END AS January,
       CASE WHEN DOJMONTH='February' OR
            (MonthNum<2 AND ((MonthNum+Months)-1)>=2)
            THEN SALARY
         ELSE NULL END AS February,
       CASE WHEN DOJMONTH='March' OR
            (MonthNum<3 AND ((MonthNum+Months)-1)>=3)
            THEN SALARY
          ELSE NULL END AS March,
       CASE WHEN DOJMONTH='April' OR
            (MonthNum<4 AND ((MonthNum+Months)-1)>=4)
            THEN SALARY
          ELSE NULL END AS April,
       CASE WHEN DOJMONTH='May' OR
            (MonthNum<5 AND ((MonthNum+Months)-1)>=5)
            THEN SALARY
          ELSE NULL END AS May,
       CASE WHEN DOJMONTH='June' OR
            (MonthNum<6 AND ((MonthNum+Months)-1)>=6)
            THEN SALARY
          ELSE NULL END AS June,
       CASE WHEN DOJMONTH='July' OR
            (MonthNum<7 AND ((MonthNum+Months)-1)>=7)
            THEN SALARY
          ELSE NULL END AS July,
       CASE WHEN DOJMONTH='August' OR
            (MonthNum<8 AND ((MonthNum+Months)-1)>=8)
            THEN SALARY
          ELSE NULL END AS August,
       CASE WHEN DOJMONTH='September' OR
            (MonthNum<9 AND ((MonthNum+Months)-1)>=9)
            THEN SALARY
          ELSE NULL END AS September,
       CASE WHEN DOJMONTH='October' OR
            (MonthNum<10 AND ((MonthNum+Months)-1)>=10)
            THEN SALARY
          ELSE NULL END AS October,
       CASE WHEN DOJMONTH='November' OR
            (MonthNum<11 AND ((MonthNum+Months)-1)>=11)
            THEN SALARY
          ELSE NULL END AS November,
       CASE WHEN DOJMONTH='December' OR
            (MonthNum<12 AND ((MonthNum+Months)-1)>=12)
            THEN SALARY
          ELSE NULL END AS December
FROM CTE
```

Comment: `CASE WHEN DOJMONTH='January' OR` You already translated the month in string to numbers why don't you use that in the query ?